# Efficiently find where any column in one data frame matches any column in another data frame

Tags: r, matrix, optimization

Consider the following two data frames:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  x1 = c('dog', 'cow', 'horse', 'rabbit', 'bear', 'seal', 'lion', 'ostrich','cat', 'hamster'),
  x2 = c(NA, 'dog', NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'hamster',NA, NA),
  x3 = c('ostrich', NA, NA, NA, 'bear', NA, NA, NA,NA, NA)
)

df2 <- data.frame(
  y1 = c('beaver', 'crow', 'donkey', 'lion', 'bear', 'fox', 'moose', 'mole'),
  y2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 'bear', NA, NA, 'moose', NA),
  y3 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
)
```

I'm looking to create a boolean matrix with `TRUE` values where any column in `df1` matches any column in `df2`. The current solution being:

```
# create one matrix for matches in each column in df1 and df2
aa <- Map(
  f = function(x, y) outer(x, y, FUN = '=='),
  df1[seq_len(ncol(df1))],
  df2[seq_len(ncol(df2))]
) 

# create higher-dimensional object
bb <- simplify2array(aa)

# collapse higher-dimensional object to single matrix
cc <- apply(bb, 1:2, function(x) {
  if (all(is.na(x))) NA else max(x, na.rm = TRUE)
})
```

This is produces the correct result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Unfortunately, this method is not efficient enough so that my machine will run out of memory when trying to solve my problem with real world data.

**How can i optimize this code?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here might be some simplifications in terms of expression (not check the performance yet)

- Using `asplit` + `outer`

```
outer(
  asplit(df1,1),
  asplit(df2,1),
  FUN = Vectorize(function(x,y) ifelse(all(is.na(u <- x==y)),NA,max(u,na.rm = TRUE)))
)
```

which gives

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

- Using `as.data.frame` + `t` + `outer`

```
outer(
  as.data.frame(t(df1)),
  as.data.frame(t(df2)),
  FUN = Vectorize(function(x,y) ifelse(all(is.na(u <- x==y)),NA,max(u,na.rm = TRUE)))
)
```

which gives

```
    V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
V1   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V2   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V3   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V4   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V5   0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
V6   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V7   0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
V8   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V9   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
V10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

- Using `outer`

```
outer(
  1:nrow(df1),
  1:nrow(df2),
  FUN = Vectorize(function(k1, k2) ifelse(all(is.na(u <- df1[k1, ] == df2[k2, ])), NA, max(u, na.rm = TRUE)))
)
```

which gives

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

- Using `Reduce` + `Map` + `outer`

```
Reduce(
  function(...) pmax(..., na.rm = TRUE),
  Map(function(x, y) outer(x, y, `==`), df1, df2)
)
```

which gives

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
 [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks, while much more elegantly expressed than the original code, it's unfortunately performing worse :( microbenchmark mean = `26.23` for original, `45.55` for this snippet.

Comment: @ComfortEagle Thanks for your feedback. I updated my solution with three other workarounds (I guess the last one would be the fastest). Could you check the performance?

Comment: Wow, thanks @ThomasIsCoding the last one really did it! `Reduce + Map + outer` was `4.5` times faster than your first post!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach :

```
mat <- +(Reduce(`|`, Map(function(x, y) outer(x, y, FUN = '=='), df1,df2)))
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0
mat
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
# [1,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [7,]    0    0    0    1    0    0    0    0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be equally quick to @ThomasIsCoding solution!